# Slowness in Orbeon page rendering when showing a group with a large number of fields

Tags: orbeon, xforms, performance-testing

I am working on Orbeon forms and i have a performance related issue as explained below.

I have a form where I have five fields initially. On the fifth dropdown field, if I select "Yes", because of `xforms:group` it shows a block of fields (the block has around 40 fields).
Since the block is in the repeated section, I can add/delete as many blocks as I can.

Now, if I add say 10 blocks and when I toggle the fifth dropdown field from any value to "Yes", it takes more than 2 seconds to display all the blocks.

I am using Orbeon Forms 3.8 and Tomcat 6 on Windows XP desktop with 2GB RAM.

Please let me know what happens when "Yes" is selected (meaning conditional display when xforms:group is true) which is taking more time to display.

```
<xforms:group ref=".[instance('form-attributes')/flag='yes']" >
    //code for the controls here
</xforms:group>
```

Comment: Troubleshooting a performance issue in the abstract is going to be hard. Note that you should give 3.9 a try, including 3.9 PE which uses an XPath dependency engine to accelerate updates.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. I have tried this in 3.9 CE but there is no big improvement. I will try PE and let you know.

Comment: Which browser have you been using for this test? If you try with IE and Chrome, do you see a significant difference? Is it much faster with Chrome than IE? If it is, I would recommend you try the full update mechanism that comes with 3.9 PE. You'll find more on this at http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-performance-settings#TOC-Full-update-mechanism

Comment: Hi, I used IE7. But form is faster in FireFox. I didnt try Chrome. I have also tried full update mechanism and performance is drastically improved even with IE7. The link was very helpful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using code that looks like:

```
<xforms:group ref=".[condition]">
    <!-- Large number of fields -->
</xforms:group>
```

1. When `condition` is false, the fields inside the group are non-relevant. The XForms engine doesn't compute their value, read-only status, validity, label, hint, help, alert, etc.
2. When `condition` becomes true, the content of the group become relevant, and the XForms engine evaluates all the controls inside the group.
3. The browser needs to apply all those changes to the DOM.

Typically, step #2 is much faster than #3, especially with IE7. To avoid the numerous updates on step #3, another way to write this code is:

```
<xhtml:div class="{if (condition) then '' else 'xforms-disabled'}">
    <!-- Large number of fields -->
</xhtml:div>
```

With this, the fields inside the `div` will always be relevant:

- The upside is that when `condition` becomes true, all the browser might need to do is to flip that class on the `div`. It won't necessarily need to update all the controls inside, unless of course their value has also changed.
- The downside is that while `condition` is false, the XForms engine, on the server, needs to keep all the controls inside the `div` up-to-date.

But more often than not, especially when you're seeing IE7 slowness, the performance you gain on the client far outweighs the increased processing that might be needed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [link](http://orbeon-forms-ops-users.24843.n4.nabble.com/Client-side-JS-code-crashes-in-IE-on-certain-structure-within-repeat-td277936.html) that seems to suggest `span` tag instead of `div` tag, though  the original post was for Code crash, the suggested work around gave a small performance improvement in my form when I tested it in IE. Hope this code will give you some benefit.